# Conceptually Question: Passing a function in an object from Backend to Frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend

Consider the following scenario:
A front-end application containing

- Create View (POST) with multiple input fields
- Edit View (GET values from back-end, PUT if values changed)
- Both views use the same route.

While a user is in the process of typing values into the inputs, there are several "helper fields" which do (live/instant) calculations based on the inputs of the user. The user is able to see the results of those calculations.

Easy enough a calculations.js located in the front-end, receives the current input values (state) and does the calculations.

Now please consider the following:
Results of calculations.js are **not** saved to the database, since they can be calculated.
**However**, the back-end has to do very similar calculations. Lets say it has to sum up the results of calculations.js in multiple routes. This speaks for putting calculations.js in the back-end. Another possibility: The Edit View shall receive the initial (calculated) values from the back-end.

The dilemma:

- Putting calculations.js only in the backend, makes it, so that the
  front-end has to call the back-end all the time while the user is filling in inputs
  (not practical).
- Putting calculations.js in both, may lead to data inconsistency and speaks against DRY Principle

In this context i was asking myself if it is possible and/or bad practice to define the function the back-end and pass it in an object to the front-end? Something like

```
{ calcFunction: (props) => console.log(props) }
```

How would someone tackle this problem in general?
Thank you

Comment: Does the code for the server exist outside of your current build, or are you coding them in parallel within the same app folder? If it's the latter you can create a "shared" folder and just _share_ the same files between the front and back-end.

Comment: Interesting thought. The projects are separated but nevertheless wouldn't that make problems at the deployment, when front and backend are deployed to different servers?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure how you were deploying, so that thought doesn't make much sense.